# python how to match multistring input

Tags: python, string

Context:
So what I am trying to do is

```py
a = 'hello world'
b = 'Hi world and hello user'
```

Rightnow I was using

```py
if a in b:
  return True
```

This does not works cause it tries to compare whole string of a in b

Is there a function in python where it compares a and b ignore the space and actually return true.

Sorry for poorly phrased question, also I cannot manipulate a and b since I am ingesting both from user

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by compare a in b

Comment: the example you are providing should be false right? or you want to see if each word is within second at any place? because the example you provide should return `False` right?

Comment: Well the example I am providing should have return ```True```

Comment: Then your description doesn't match your expected output. Please clarify.

Comment: Both *a* and *b* are strings (which are immutable) so it's unclear what you mean by "manipulate"

Answer (score 2):

Given two strings (sentences) the objective appears to be to determine if all words in one sentence occur in another. In which case:

```
def is_in(a, b):
    return set(a.split()).issubset(set(b.split()))

print(is_in('hello user', 'hi world and hello user'))
print(is_in('hello world', 'hi world and hello user'))
print(is_in('goodbye user', 'hi world and hello user'))
```

**Output:**

```
True
True
False
```

Comment: Clean and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way would be:

```
import re

a = 'hell world'
b = 'Hi world and hello user'

def match(a,b):
    count = 0
    for a_wd in a:
        for b_wd in b:
            if re.findall('\\b' + a_wd + '\\b', b_wd):
                count += 1
    print(str(count))
    if count >= len(a.split()):
        return True
    else:
        return False

output = match(a,b)
print(output)
```

Comment: Change *a* to 'hell world' and this will return True. Is that your intention?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of the words in `a` and then check if they are in `b`.

```py
a = 'hello world'
b = 'hi world and hello user'

#Split the sentence into words
set_a = set(a.split(" "))
set_b = set(b.split(" "))

#check if all the items from 'a' are in 'b'
if set_a.issubset(set_b):
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there a function in python where it compares a and b ignore the space and actually return true."

If you want to do that you could `use a.replace(" ") in b` but that would still yield `False`, so I'm going to make an assumption you're trying to check the words of `a` against `b`.

I think what you're trying to do is check if every word in `a` is in `b`. If that is the case, loop over `a.split()`. That way you aren't changing 'a' and you can easily check if they are all in b (`word in b for word in a.split()`, see the code below).

```py
a = 'hello world'
b = 'Hi world and hello user'

# added []'s around [word in b] for clarity
check = all([word in b] for word in a.split())

print(check)
# >>> True
print(a)
# >> hello world < a stays unchanged
```